# Matching two lists to determine whether any values match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have two lists I want to match.  For the top example, there is `q,w,e,r,t,y` and I want to match it with `a.s.d.f.g` but no match exists. (I want all values to be unique; if even 1 matches, that is considered a match).

In the bottom example, `q,w,e,r,t,y` matches with `a,s,r,f,g` since `r` exists in both lists.

Can a formula indicate that?   Any form of indication will work, such as returning `r` (the matching value), or `TRUE`, or `1, 0`.

This needs to be scalable.

[image: Excel example]

Answer (score 1):

You want a formula that returns if any value in a column corresponds to any value in a different row... there's a nice trick to do this, it's a bit hacky but it works, do this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(A11:A16=D11:H11))
```

What this does is basically compare all cells in both vectors, all non matching cells are treated as **0** and matching cells will be treated as **1**, so you will end up with a sum of all of those values.

As an additional bonus, you will know how many letters match, so ***it will return 0, 1, 2, ... etc*** depending on how many values match

No match:

[image: no match]

Match:

[image: match]

Just please keep in mind that this formula **will only work for vectors**, meaning, one row compared to one column.

Comment: Just added the images, regarding the other answers, they might be helpful to other people, not sure if they need to go

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest you the Formula which will **Compare and Count Match/Duplicate in two list,** where values are between 2 Columns or even between Column and Row.*

```
For Two Columns    =SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A7,B2:B7,0))))

For Column & Row   =SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A7,B2:H2,0))))
```

*Hope this help you.*